# Why is my date modified before date created in Lubuntu OS?

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu

I know that when the date modified comes before date created, it means that file has been copied or created for the first time in the file system. But I have only heard of this happening in Windows OS, and not in Linux. Do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You've provided no clues as to release of Lubuntu, nor file-system (and with file metadata the file-system really matters!) but you can manually set/change those values too on many systems, thus unless you have *full specific details* of the system where the file is located - I'd not trust the metadata (*what you see in a directory can be a filtered view of what is actually on the file-system itself! unless you have full details - which you didn't provide!*)

Comment: For chitchat, I had an old Windows and Fedora dual boot machine a long time ago. Windows system resets the clock at a local time as a system clock when I booted in, and Linux system does as an UTC. Each time I booted into a different one, the clock lost or gained time for some hours.